# Getting the values of all checkbox checked in a group as comma separated

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a group of checkbox

```
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely1" value="1">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely1">Monday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely2" value="2">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely2">Tuesday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely3" value="3">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely3">Wednesday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely4" value="4">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely4">Thursday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely5" value="5">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely5">Friday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely6" value="6">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely6">Saterday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely7" value="7">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely7">Sunday</label>
</div>
```

When the checkbox values are changing I want to get the checked values of checkbox as an array or comma separated value using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give class to your check box and use `map`  to push your selected value like below.

```js
$(".chkDay").change(function() {
  var arr = $(".chkDay:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
    //  return $(this).next('label').text(); // If you want sunday , monday ... on array , uncomment this line comment above line. 
  }).get();
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely1" value="1" class="chkDay">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely1">Monday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely2" value="2" class="chkDay">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely2">Tuesday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely3" value="3" class="chkDay">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely3">Wednesday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely4" value="4" class="chkDay">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely4">Thursday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely5" value="5" class="chkDay">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely5">Friday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely6" value="6" class="chkDay">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely6">Saterday</label>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
<div class="check_parent">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely" id="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely7" value="7" class="chkDay">
  <label for="cmsms_which_days_are_you_most_likely7">Sunday</label>
</div>
```